# Proper way to include resources from bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I have a bundle with this structure:

```
/src/BankBundle/
    ...
    /src/BankBundle/Resources/
        ...
        public/
            css/
                foundation-datepicker.css
            js/
                common.js
                foundation-datepicker.js
        ...
    ...
```

So I want to include the CSS and JS in my template and I'm doing in this way:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block javascripts %} 
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('/js/foundation-datepicker.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('/js/common.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script> 
{% endblock %} 

{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<link href="{{ asset('/css/foundation-datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

But it's not working as Firebug console says **404 Error: not found** so what's the right way to include resources from my bundle? I also run the task `php app/console assets:install --symlink` so I've symlinks to those files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've setup the symlinks you  should be able to do:

```
{{ asset( 'bundles/lowercasebundlename/js/foundation-datepicker.js' ) }}
```

But it may still be better to just let Assetic dump the files for you like:

```
{% javascripts '@BundleName/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at how the symlinked folders look.

They are of the form `bundles/<bundlename-without-Bundle>` ...

The paths generated by the `asset()` function are relative to your `web` folder.

```
{{ asset('bundles/bank/css/foundation-datepicker.css') }}
```

You can aswell use the `@Bundle` syntax but please note that some filters ( i.e. `cssrewrite` ) won't work using this syntax.

```
{% stylesheets '@BankBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"> 
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony installs bundle resources in the `bundles` directory under `/web`.  I believe the correct path would be /bundles/bank/css/xxx.css:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/bank/css/foundation-datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```